# VB.Net: Resizing ListBoxView Column When Form Resizes

Tags: vb.net, listbox, resize, width

How can I have a single column resize with the form so that the ListView columns continue to fill the whole form?

Comment: Is your qustion about ListBox with MultiColumn set to true?

Comment: No, it's the "ListView" control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, implement the listview's Resize event handler and calculate the space left for the column.  For example:

```
Private Sub ListView1_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Resize
    Dim resizeColumn As Integer = 1
    Dim w As Integer = 0
    For column As Integer = 0 To ListView1.Columns.Count - 1
        if column <> resizeColumn then w += ListView1.Columns(column).Width
    Next
    w = ListView1.ClientSize.Width - w - 1 - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth
    If w > 0 Then ListView1.Columns(resizeColumn).Width = w
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    ListView1_Resize(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    MyBase.OnLoad(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked well, however how can I select which column to resize?

Comment: Herpderp.

Which part? I tried changing almost all the variables and got no good results.

Comment: @Ben: code updated.  Change "resizeColumn" to the column you want to get resized.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hans, appreciate it!

Comment: @Ben, this wasn't helpful?  Sounds like it was, a "this was helpful" upvote is appropriate perhaps.